# How does self play work in RL?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning, artificial-intelligence

I try  to understand  how  self play worl  in Reinforcement  learning with ppo2.

Do i have one model  which predicts  an action  for  both  sides? If  yes,  do  i  Update the model  with  experiences  from both  sides? In this  case  Player A and B  always  belong  to the same Model?

Or  do  i  have  a copy  of the  agent  which  generates  actions  for  the  right  player  and  is  updated  after same time  with the weights  of  the  left  agent?

Thanks!